# WooCommerce Order goes from Completed to On-Hold itself

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Order that was previously marked as Completed in 1-2 days again falls into "on hold".

Delivery plugin code:

```
/**
 * Check if WooCommerce is active
 */
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

    function your_shipping_method_init2() {
        if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method2' ) ) {
            class WC_Your_Shipping_Method2 extends WC_Shipping_Method {
                /**
                 * Constructor for your shipping class
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function __construct() {
                    $this->id                 = 'dopdostavka2'; // Id for your shipping method. Should be uunique.
                    $this->method_title       = __( 'Дополнительная доставка ' );  // Title shown in admin
                    $this->method_description = __( 'Транспортная компания ' ); // Description shown in admin

                    $this->enabled            = "yes"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced enabled
                    $this->title              = "Транспортная компания"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced.

                    $this->init();
                }

                /**
                 * Init your settings
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @return void
                 */
                function init() {
                    // Load the settings API
                    $this->init_form_fields(); // This is part of the settings API. Override the method to add your own settings
                    $this->init_settings(); // This is part of the settings API. Loads settings you previously init.

                    // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
                    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
                }

                /**
                 * calculate_shipping function.
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @param mixed $package
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
                    $rate = array(
                        'id' => $this->id,
                        'label' => $this->title,
                        'cost' => '0',
                        'calc_tax' => 'per_item'
                    );

                    // Register the rate
                    $this->add_rate( $rate );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'your_shipping_method_init2' );

    function add_your_shipping_method2( $methods ) {
        $methods['your_shipping_method2'] = 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method2';
        return $methods;
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_your_shipping_method2' );
}
```

Comment: You should explain and word better your question and add some source reference for your code like where have you pick that customized code. Now why are you adding this "Additional delivery" method? I don't think that you need that… So please update your question with more details and your shipping config too, explaining why (or or what) you need that "Additional delivery" shipping method…  It should give you more chances to have a useful answer.